# Solving simultaneous equations in Sage

Tags: python, math, equation, algebra, sage

In [Sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_%28mathematics_software%29) (using the Sage terminal in [Sage Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com)), I expected the following to yield the result `[t == (1/2)]`. However, it yields the result `[]`.

```
sage: var('x1 y1 x2 y2 t')
(x1, y1, x2, y2, t)
sage: eq1 = x1==t
sage: eq2 = y1==t
sage: eq3 = x2==t
sage: eq4 = y2==1-t
sage: solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,x1==x2,y1==y2],t)
[]
```

The following reformulation doesn't help:

```
sage: eq5 = x1==x2
sage: eq6 = y1==y2
sage: solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6],t)
[]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write

```
solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,x1==x2,y1==y2],t)
```

Then `t` is the variable you are solving for and `x1, x2, y1, y2` are **free** parameters. There is obviously no solution which is valid for any value of those parameter. However, if you ask:

```
solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,x1==x2,y1==y2],t,x1,x2,y1,y2)
```

Then you get what you expect:

```
[[t == (1/2), x1 == (1/2), x2 == (1/2), y1 == (1/2), y2 == (1/2)]]
```

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a concise way to ask for only the `t` value of the solution to be output?

Comment: Maybe `solution_dict` can help.